# Use math in PhpStorm's Live Template

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

How can I use math in PhpStorm's Live Template?

For example, I have `$Image_width$` in my template and want to set height image something like this:

```
<img width="$Image_width$" height="($Image_width$ / 2)">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groovyScript()` function to define custom expressions - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/template-variables.html#predefined_functions.

For example, for template like:

```
<img width="$Image_width$" height="$Image_width_half$">
```

you can specify `groovyScript("def res=_1 as Integer; return res /2 ", Image_width)` as expression for `$Image_width_half$` variable:

[image]

`_1` here is a reference to first variable passed as a parameter to `groovyScript()` function